# Duplicate Override ARM Template Parameters while doing deployment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template

I am testing the Azure data factory deployment using ARM Templates, where I am deploying the all the ADF Instances (Data factory pipeline, linked services, data sets, data flow, Trigger etc.) from Development to UAT and Production, but before deploying to UAT and production. I included below activity in Azure DevOps pipeline-

1. Stopping the ADF Trigger using 'Azure PowerShell' in built task of azure Devops release pipeline. In this task I am using the Inline script to stop trigger before deployment to UAT/PROD environment.
2. ARM Template deployment = using ARM Template I configured following value in it.

Template -> the ARM template of the pipeline ARMTemplateForFactory.json
Template Parameters -> the ARM \TemplateParametrsForFactory.json
Override template Parameter-> When I tried to enter the Values for UAT/Prod environment. some parameter are showing double.

Q-1. PFA, the details about each step and the logs. Please guide me why trigger not taking proper format. what could be the reason behind this? How should I correct this so that it can take trigger parameters only once.

Q-2. Also Please let me know Do I need Azure function app key for UAT/Prod environment to enter that value while override template parameter? Can someone please take a look and guide me what I am missing here?

Thanks
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered in [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/832984/index.html) platform. Thank you @sachingupta-1921 and @MartinJaffer-MSFT for the workable solution, posting it as an answer here to help the other community members.

A-1: Changing the name of the triggers without spaces resolved the problem mentioned in Q-1.

A-2: If you have different keys for dev / uat/ prod, then you would definitely need to include that.
Since you have a Key Vault, you could put the Function App key in there, and let it be taken care of by the change of key vaults. Then you would not need to enter the Function App key in the parameters.